# SQL Query to concat duplicated row

Tags: sql, db2

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns with the following values

---

```
| A | B | C |
| A1| B1| C |
| A | B | C1|
_____________
```

I'd like to make a query to get

```
A | B | C, C1|
A1| B1| C|
```

to get distinct First & Second Column. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use [listagg](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html)..

```
SELECT
  cola, 
  colb,
  LISTAGG(colc, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY colc) AS colc
FROM mytable
GROUP BY
  cola, 
  colb
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It doesn't work for me I can run the group by, but with the line LISTAGG I get the following error. An error occurred while executing the query.
ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0199 - Keyword GROUP not expected. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.
Any other solution without using LISTAGG?